# What parameters to use to compare GUI frameworks / toolkits?

Tags: frameworks, comparison, gui

I'm doing some research on the best GUI toolkit to use for future products at the company. We're talking about a fairly large organizations with quite a bit of code and a complete rewrite project in planning. Don't ask.

Anyway, I'm trying to create a list relevant parameters to judge the toolkits. What would you use to drive the comparison?

Here's what I've got so far:

- Maturity
- Ease of development
- Ease of prototyping
- Ease of maintenance
- Size of hiring pool
- Available knowledge at the company
- Training costs
- Community size
- Community level of expertise (how hard to find good answers to complex problems)
- Amount of expert-level books available
- Ability to interface to other technologies
- Deployment considerations
- Visual aesthetics
- Ability to access OS resources
- Multiple monitor support (something that might come in handy in our particular application)

Comment: you are missing architecture as a development criterium.

Answer (score 1):

and the answer is.... Qt

seriously, it does fit all your points; and on top of it it's multiplatform and really efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would add extensibility and versatility (or power) because I consider it different from "ease of development". YMMV.

For ex QT3 (or was it the version before that Oh Well) is very easy to use as compared to MFC for typical cases, but where you wanted to do something atypical it came up short. I hear they have changed this in QT4.

Good list BTW.